# How to resolve authorization error while writing to synapse dedicated pool table from Azure Databricks using Pyspark using databricks service principl

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-synapse, polybase

I am using a databricks service principal which has

Storage Blob Data Contributor access on ADLS
db_datareader, db_datawriter, db_ddladmin permission on synapse dedicated sql pool

I am using below code snippet to write the data to synapse table:

[image]

I can see that the tempDir gets the data while trying to copy :

[image]

But the overall process fails with below message:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-1252066294211483>:8
      1 df.write \
      2   .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
      3     .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://"+azure_synapse_server_name+":1433;database="+azure_synapse_database_name) \
      4     .option("enableServiceprincipalAuth","true") \
      5     .option("tempDir","abfss://silver@xyz.dfs.core.windows.net/temp_area") \
      6     .option("dbtable", "dbo."+EntityName) \
      7     .mode("append") \
----> 8     .save()

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/instrumentation_utils.py:48, in _wrap_function.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     46 start = time.perf_counter()
     47 try:
---> 48     res = func(*args, **kwargs)
     49     logger.log_success(
     50         module_name, class_name, function_name, time.perf_counter() - start, signature
     51     )
     52     return res

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py:1396, in DataFrameWriter.save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
   1394     self.format(format)
   1395 if path is None:
-> 1396     self._jwrite.save()
   1397 else:
   1398     self._jwrite.save(path)

File /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py:162, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    160 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    161     try:
--> 162         return f(*a, **kw)
    163     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    164         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o921.save.
: com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDWSideException: Azure Synapse Analytics failed to execute the JDBC query produced by the connector.
Underlying SQLException(s):
  - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Not able to validate external location because The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. [ErrorCode = 105215] [SQLState = S0001]
         
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.Utils$.wrapExceptions(Utils.scala:735)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.$anonfun$sideEffectResult$1(commands.scala:82)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$3(QueryExecution.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$2(QueryExecution.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:1038)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:360)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$withMVTagsIfNecessary(QueryExecution.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:519)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:519)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:312)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:495)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1(QueryExecution.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:372)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:964)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:429)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:258)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:397)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:306)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:195)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.executeInterruptibly(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:137)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.$anonfun$executeInterruptibly$1(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:115)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.$anonfun$executeInterruptibly$1$adapted(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:115)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.withPreparedStatement(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:362)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.executeInterruptibly(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:115)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDwWriter.$anonfun$saveToSqlDW$6(SqlDwWriter.scala:249)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:377)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:363)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.SparkDatabricksProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:34)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDwWriter.$anonfun$saveToSqlDW$1(SqlDwWriter.scala:206)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDwWriter.$anonfun$saveToSqlDW$1$adapted(SqlDwWriter.scala:73)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.withConnection(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:340)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDwWriter.saveToSqlDW(SqlDwWriter.scala:73)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.DefaultSource.$anonfun$createRelation$3(DefaultSource.scala:131)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.Utils$.wrapExceptions(Utils.scala:698)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Not able to validate external location because The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:265)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1676)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:620)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:540)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7627)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3916)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:268)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:242)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:518)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.$anonfun$executeInterruptibly$2(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:115)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.$anonfun$executeInterruptibly$2$adapted(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:115)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.$anonfun$executeInterruptibly$3(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:129)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

---

Could someone please suggest what is this 403 error for ?

Comment: @alexott - could you please guide here?

Comment: Check out this link for the access policies required for `COPY` statement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/archive/azure/synapse-polybase#--required-azure-synapse-permissions-for-the-copy-statement

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Hi,

I was able to resolve it by creating a database scoped credential inside synapse and then creating anexternal location for tempdir where I am landing the temp data.

Below is the code snippet that was used:

```
df.write \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://"+azure_synapse_server_name+":1433;database="+azure_synapse_database_name) \
    .option("enableServiceprincipalAuth","true") \
    .option("useAzureMSI","true") \
    .option("tempDir",temp_path) \
    .option("dbtable", "dbo."+EntityName) \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()
```

Please note that I used service principal for reading from lake using databricks and Azure MSI cred ( database scoped cred) is being used for load to synapse

Thanks